# Changing appearance of items in ListBox without changing / getting raw SelectedItem value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I am binding `ListBoxes` on `Properties.Settings` `StringCollection` this way

```
 <ListBox Height="52" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,0,0,148" Name="FolderList" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default},Path=Folders}"/>
```

I realized then that I do not want to display the foldernames raw (as they are hidden shared folders that end with $). I want to display them Title-cased on the ListBox and trimmed of the final dollar sign, so I implemented an `IValueConverter` that goes through the `StringCollection`

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    StringCollection raws = (StringCollection)value;
    StringCollection output = new StringCollection();
    foreach (string raw in raws)
    {
        bool hasDollar = false;
        if (raw.Last() == '$') hasDollar = true; 
        TextInfo myTI = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;
        output.Add(hasDollar ? myTI.ToTitleCase(raw.Substring(0, raw.Length - 1))
            : myTI.ToTitleCase(raw));
    }
    return output;
}
```

It works. My question is:

When I do my button_click event to get the SelectedItem, what is a *clean* way that I get the raw (unconverted) string? I can probably access the Properties directly, count indices and compare, but there may be a cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to go about it without having to write a custom converter to strip off 1 character. Have a look at the code I have tossed together. It's seudo code but it should give you an idea.

```
FolderObject
{
    private string _name;
    public string name 
    { 
        get { return this._name; } 
        set
        {
            this._name = value.trim( new char[]{ '$' } )
        }
    }

    private string _raw;
    public string raw 
    { 
        get { return this._raw; }  
        set { this._raw = value; }
    }
}

class form1 : Form
{
    private List<FolderObject> _folders;
    private BindingSource _bindingSource;

    public form1()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        _folders = new List<FolderObject>();
        _bindingSource = new BindingSource();

        List<FolderObject> folders = new List<FolderObject>();
        //Fill folders ...

        _bindingSource.DataSource = folders;

        //bind collection to listbox
        listbox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        listbox1.ValueMember = "Raw";
        listbox1.DataSource = _bindingSource;
    }

    button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.format("Folder name is: {0}, Raw name is: {1}", listbox1.SelectedMember, listbox1.SelectedValue));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll look into this if I don't get any more answers. but I would really rather prefer finding a way that keeps my XAML bound to the properties instead of binding it on runtime since those values don't get repopulated during execution. I also implemented the Converter thinking that I could use ConvertBack to do what I want but I don't think I can do anything related with it